# Toggle between two controls

Tags: jquery

I have a toggle button and I have two divs and each div will contain a control, and when I click the toggle button then one needs to show and the other needs to hide and vice versa. 
Normally this wouldn't be a problem and I would just use toggle if using one div, but kinda stuck on this one...
As you see I have a class called 'hide' and its currently hiding div b. When I click on the button then b should be seen and div a should be hidden and vice versa.

I was using an if statement and it started getting muddled up and started overlapping.

In short I need to swap the hide class between the two divs

```js
$('#btn').on('click', () => {

});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
}

.b {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"> A </div>
  <div class="b hide"> B </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: You could always make a CSS class called unhide, which has no properties and apply that to the div which is to be shown on page load, then just grab the div with unhide, remove class unhide and add class hide, grab div with class hide and remove it and add class unhide.

Comment: @RyanWilson, I was trying that earlier but couldn't get it working right

Comment: added an example answer below.

Comment: @Chris Posted an answer, I guess that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not a problem at all.
Just do the following:

1. Define `display: none;` for class `.b`
2. just *toggle* both `.a` and `.b` simply getting them together

   in jquery selector: `$(".a, .b").toggle();`

```js
$('#btn').on('click', () => {
$(".a, .b").toggle();
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
}

.b {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"> A </div>
  <div class="b"> B </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Even if you're eager to use class `.hide` you can write for your snippet `$(".a, .b").toggleClass('hide');`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I chose this as the answer because of the minimal amount of code

Answer (score 1):

You need some assurance that what are the 2 `div`'s you will be playing with for toggling.

So let's say you have here, those `div` inside a `div` with class `container`.

Now you will have to check if any `div` inside having `hide` must have it removed and the one who does not should have the class `hide` added.

**Solution below:**

```js
$('#btn').on('click', () => {
  $(".container > div").toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
}

.b {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"> A </div>
  <div class="b hide"> B </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}
//class for the div that is being shown
.unhide {
  display:block;
}

//have div 1 with class unhide initially
<div class="a unhide"> A </div>
<div class="b hide"> B </div>

//Grab both divs then remove classes and add classes
$('#btn').on('click', () => {
    $divToHide = $('div.unhide');
    $divToShow = $('div.hide');

    $divToHide.removeClass('unhide').addClass('hide');
    $divToShow.removeClass('hide').addClass('unhide');
});
```